# How can i understand my model overfit or underfit from root mean squared error?

Tags: data-science, data-mining

I know this interpretation with R square but, I have to do it with root mean squared error.

For example: For the training set i have root mean squared error for the 2nd degree 32.5, 3rd degree 29.2, 4th degree 27.5. On the other side, for the validation set i have root mean squared error for the 2nd degree 34.2, 3rd degree 32.3, 4th degree 35.8. I have some interpretation on it, i guess 4th degree is overfitting but i could not interpret anything for 2nd and 3rd degree.

Answer (score 0):

The degree in your case represents model complexity. The model will generally perform better on the training set as you increase complexity -- the RMSE will decline. Also the performance on the validation set will generally increase as the model gets more complex because it will be able to capture the patterns in the data better. But this holds only until some point. When your model gets too complex (in your case the degree gets too high), it will copy the data too tightly and won't generalize -- its performance on the data it hadn't seen during training will suffer. The unseen data is your validation set. In your case, the step in complexity from 2nd degree to 3rd degree increased performance on both the training set and the validation set. However, when you tried 4th degree model, its performance on the validation set declined. That's the sign of overfitting.